# Annoying heap corruption in c++

Tags: visual-c++

I was trying to implement the Genetic Algorithms in c++. I combined it with my previous BP network project and then the problem comes. When I tried to feed it with some complicate data, ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)) error pops up.

Below is my main body of this part

```
 float NeuralNetwork::Optimize()
  {

    TotalFitness = 0;
    std::list<SPopulation>::iterator Data;

    if( Population.size() == 0)
        Population = InitializePopulation();

    for( Data = Population.begin(); Data!=Population.end(); ++Data )
    {       
        Clean((*Data).Data.y);
        (*Data).Data.y = Predict( (*Data).Data.x );

        SVector Expected = GetTruth( (*Data).Data.x );

        float Temp = 0;
        for( int i=0; i<Expected.Size; i++ )
        {
            Temp += powf( Expected.Data[i] - (*Data).Data.y.Data[i], 2 );
        }
        Clean( Expected );

        (*Data).Fitness = Temp/2;
        TotalFitness += (*Data).Fitness;
        (*Data).Fitness = 1 / (1+(*Data).Fitness);  
    }

    TotalFitness /= Population.size();
    TotalFitness = 1 / (1+TotalFitness);

    Select();
    Cross();
    Mutate();

    return TotalFitness;
}
```

std::list Population is a private member of my Network class. Usually after I trained it for 4 or 5 times it will crash at the first Clean function.

```
void NeuralNetwork::Clean( SVector& x )
{        
    if( (x.Size != 0) && (x.Data != NULL) )
    {
        //cout<<"Delete pointer at address :"<<hex<<x.Data<<endl;
        delete[] x.Data;        
        x.Size = 0;
        x.Data = NULL;      
    }
}

void NeuralNetwork::Clean( SData& x )
{
    Clean( x.x );
    Clean( x.y );
}
```

And then the real strange thing happens, when I delete the Mutate() function, everything works. But there's nothing in Mutate function could cause this problem.

```
void NeuralNetwork::Mutate( )
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    double x;  
    double PMutation = 0.20;
    if( Population.size() == 0 )
        return;
    std::list<SPopulation>::iterator It;
    for( It = Population.begin(); It!=Population.end(); ++It )
    {
        for( int i=0; i<mCreateInfo.InputNodes; i++ )
        {
            x = rand()%1000/1000.0; 
            if (x < PMutation) 
            {
                SVector S = (*It).Data.x;
                float NewValue = (((float)(rand()%1000)/1000.0)*(mBoundHigh - mBoundLow) + mBoundLow);
                S.Data[0] = NewValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mCreateInfo.InputNodes is always 0 in my test. I start to think what could cause the problem. Then I realize only in the Select() function I erase some entities from the Population list. But that also can't be the problem. Because if I remove the Select function and Cross() function only leave Mutate() there it still crashes.

I really have no idea what could cause the error now.

ps:

Now it sometimes also crashes here. This is unbelievable. After I get the Expected object， even I clean it directly there errors still pops up. It can't be trying to delete a pointer twice.

```
SVector Expected = GetTruth( (*Data).Data.x );

float Temp = 0;
for( int i=0; i<Expected.Size; i++ )
{
    Temp += powf( Expected.Data[i] - (*Data).Data.y.Data[i], 2 );
}
Clean( Expected );
```

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of manually allocated and deallocated arrays, and see if that helps.  You're probably deleting the same block twice.

Comment: anyway, I'll try to see if it works. I was wondering could it caused by something else like: another piece of the code running from my main program damage the heap?

Comment: Yes, any out-of-bounds write to an array can damage heap data stored next to your data, causing a failure later during allocation or deallocation.

Comment: THX, solved, it's due to another piece of code trying to write across the bound. Now it works perfectly.